# UIButton tintColor for disabled and enabled state?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a custom `class` that inherits from `UIButton`. The thing that I want to accomplish is setting the `tintColor` property based on the button's enabled state (i.e enabled or disabled).

Is there any way to achieve that?

This is my class:

```
class ButtonsPostMenu: UIButton
{
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Font_AvenirNext_Medium, size: 14)
        tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Comment: **Not sure how to do that programmatically though**: How did you accomplish that differently?

Comment: @EridB - I chose my words poorly. Ignore that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could override the isEnabled property to achieve that. The tintColor will be automatically changed according to the button's isEnabled status:

```
class ButtonsPostMenu:UIButton {

    //......

    override var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet{
            if self.isEnabled {
                self.tintColor = UIColor.white
            }
            else{
                self.tintColor = UIColor.gray
            }
        }
    }

    //......

}
```

Comment: Also used this to change `tintColor` for highlighted state by overriding `isHighlighted`

Answer (score 4):

This is your class: Add `changeStateOfButton` custom method for manage tint color of `UIButton`

```
class ButtonsPostMenu: UIButton
{
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: Font_AvenirNext_Medium, size: 14)
        tintColor = UIColor.white
    }

    func changeStateOfButton() {
       if self.isEnabled {
           self.tintColor = UIColor.red // Set your color when button is enabled 
       }
       else {
           self.tintColor = UIColor.yellow // Set your color when button is disabled
       }
  }
}
```

And just call above method like when you want to set color based on enable/disable `UIButton`.

Answer (score 2):

You can attempt to replicate the `setX(_ x: X, forState: State)` API like this:

```
private class TintColorButton: UIButton {

    private var tintDict: [State.RawValue: UIColor] = [:]
    private var store: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        publisher(for: \.isHighlighted).sink { [weak self] _ in self?.applyTintColor() }.store(in: &store)
        publisher(for: \.isEnabled).sink { [weak self] _ in self?.applyTintColor() }.store(in: &store)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setTintColor(_ color: UIColor?, forState state: State) {
        tintDict[state.rawValue] = color
        applyTintColor()
    }

    private func applyTintColor() {
        tintColor = tintDict[state.rawValue] ?? tintDict[State.normal.rawValue]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor, forState: UIControlState) {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), color.CGColor)
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1))
let colorImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

self.setBackgroundImage(colorImage, forState: forState)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think image filtering is a good option.

```
btn.setImage(image, for: UIControl.State.normal)
btn.setImage(image.disabled, for: UIControl.State.disabled)
```

Use CoreImage to do image filter

```
extension UIImage{
    var disabled: UIImage?{
        let ciImage = CIImage(image: self)
        let grayscale = ciImage?.applyingFilter("CIColorControls",
                                                parameters: [ kCIInputSaturationKey: 0.0 ])
        if let gray = grayscale{
            return UIImage(ciImage: gray)
        }
        else{
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, in Swift 5